# Amazon Linux - update path to java

Tags: path

I downloaded a fuller version of java, and I wanted to update the default path to java. I tried updating the bashrc file as they did here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/ , but that did not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you change `1.5.0_07` to the version you downloaded?  Where did you install the new version?  Was it an `.rpm`, a `.tar`, a `.bin`, or something else?  Where and how did you download the new version?  Which URL or command did you use?

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded it, etc. and set the path variable to that location. But it looks in the previous location first. (i.e. if I run 'which java', it gives the path to the old download. Is there a way (other than by just moving the old java) to reorder the places that it looks for java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your new java path to the beginning of the `PATH` variable. Check the following example.

```
export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7/bin:$PATH
```

Then, type source `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc` to reload the path settings.

Comment: oh my, that's all it was :/ thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Also I needed to do this export `JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/`
Where `/usr/local/java/` is a symbolic link for the current version of java that you want the server to use.
Also in the `/etc/profile` file I set the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_31/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers. Edit your first one and include all relevant information. Each answer should stand alone, so please explain the entire process you followed in a single post then delete the other one. Finally, changing links in `/etc/alternatives` manually is not a good idea, that's what `update-alternatives` is for. In this case, `update-java-alternatives`.